# Select is not valid at this position----MYSQL is driving me nuts

Tags: mysql, select

I was doing MYSQL and the error kept popping out even I typed exactly as the online course script

It kept saying "SELECT is not valid at this position for this version....."  Anyone can help please?
Below is the script

```
use mavenfuzzyfactory;


SELECT 
website_sessions.device_type, 
count(distinct website_session.website_session_id) AS session,
count(distinct order.order_id) AS orders

FROM website_sessions

left join 
on website_session.websit_session_id= order.website_session_id

WHERE website_sessions.created_at< '2012-05-11'
      AND utm_source= 'gsearch'
      AND utm_campaign= 'nonbrand'
GROUP BY 1
```

Comment: you miss a table name after the left join and before the on clause. should be left join order. Also you have a typo website_session.websit_session_id will probably be website_session.website_session_id

Comment: And note that order is a reserved word, making it a less than ideal choice for a table/column identifier.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you want this...

```
SELECT s.device_type
     , count(distinct s.website_session_id) session
     , count(distinct o.order_id) orders
  FROM website_sessions s
  left 
  join `order` o
    on o.website_session_id = s.websit_session_id 
 WHERE s.created_at < '2012-05-11'
   AND utm_source = 'gsearch'
   AND utm_campaign= 'nonbrand'
 GROUP 
    BY 1
```

Comment: Yeah cool, it was the left join order on... . Thanks it worked a treat!